# Not able to pick up correct configuration setting for a node module

Tags: node.js, config, node-config

I am using config npm package to manage different environment setting with cross-env.
I have developed a node_module which has its own config directory and contains a `dev.json` settings file and reading it as `config.get("dbName");`
I am using this node_module in another app which also has its own `dev.json` settings file.
When I run this parent app like `set NODE_ENV=dev node app.js`
that `node_modules` which I developed it reads settings my parent app config.
and my app breaks because it doesn't have `config.get("dbName");`

I have tried doing `var config = require("config").load();`